# how to bind the database value to a div?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datalist

in my application i want to bind the data to a div, which is in a datalist so how can i bind the value .thank you

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: i have a datalist in datalist itemtemplate contain div then how can i bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Panel` that contains a `Literal` control. The `Panel` will render as a `div` and the `Literal` control renders as text. You will data bind to the `Literal` control's `Text` property. This will give you what you want. A `div` that contains text for each item displayed in a `DataList` control.

Be creative in combining controls to give you the layout, format, data-binding, and so on that you need. If it gets too complex, create a user-control

Answer (score 1):

use this is very useful

```
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLocationId" Text='<%#Eval("LocationID") %>' ></asp:Label>

       <asp:Panel Wrap="true" ID="Panel1" Width="140px" Font-Underline="true" Font-Italic="true" ForeColor="Black" ScrollBars="None" runat="server">
       <%-- <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>--%>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Solution") %>'>
        </asp:Literal>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use <%# Eval("Name of your data field") %> to bind to properties in your datasource.

Comment: i have a datalist in datalist itemtemplate contain div then how can i bind mr. ryudice